# How to rename a big collection of files numerically, ordered based on "Date modified"?

Tags: windows-7, rename, comparison, date-modified

I am using Windows 7;

I have about 1400 small images of type: `*.png`

Each image has a random name, but it has a specific date it was created at; that is "**Date modified**".

What I need to do is to re-name all of the images like this:

1.png
2.png
3.png
...
...
1400.png

So that image: *1.png* is the oldest one compared to its "Date modified", whereas the image *1400.png* is the newest one compared to its "Date modified".

How to achieve this with the lowest cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by date modified, highlight all images, right-click first image, and hit rename. Type the name such as test and they will rename in order starting with test (1), test (2), etc. Do this all the time for hyperlapse.

Comment: Nice, I used your answer, and I removed the word *test* and the brackets *()* using Bulk Rename Utility so that the result is only the number 1.png, 2.png, ect; Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) can probably achieve what you want. It has a lot of features so be sure to check out the docs and faq.